# Best practise to treat possible errors in .NET Marshal Class

Tags: .net, marshalling

What is the best way to treat errors in calls like:

```
string myString = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(wParam);
Int32 myInt = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
```

?

[edit]

Based on Hans Passant's answer, I want to share the link to [MS description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The best way? Proactively avoid them! ;)

Comment: ...what I do when ever possible!

Comment: What kind of errors are you talking about?

Comment: Errors I can't get using .net's standard exceptions based on the Exception Class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way here is the best way where ever you get an exception, don't do anything.  Windows sent you a bad message, you have **no idea** why.  You cannot handle an exception if you have no clue what caused it and what the consequences might be.  Swallowing it just causes your program to operate incorrectly without any hint to the user why.  There is no way to test this scenario.

Don't catch it, let it terminate your application.

Focus on writing a good event handler for AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException instead.

Comment: What I red from MSDN, the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException acts on the whole application. Am I right when I think it has to be implemented in the application itselfe and not in a DLL where the Marshal operations are?